# What is the best way to refactor validation logic and regular expressions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, refactoring

Let's say you have several models that contain fields for address, postal code, province/country, phone number, etc.

These are rather common fields that have specific regular expression validations. If you put the same validations and regular expressions in each model, it is duplicated. Also, the tests are duplicated. This is a smell ;)

What is the best approach using ruby and rails to refactor these types of things? A module?

In Java with Hibernate, we'd use a Component class to store the address, and then we'd put the validation logic there. Each model that wanted to use an address would simply contain one, and it will get all the address validation logic.

What is the approach to achieve the same thing in rails? Thanks!

Comment: Your module idea seems spot on to me. I would create a module with the appropriate functionality and then mix it in.

Comment: You might also consider moving the address columns into a separate table and using a polymorphic association (ie. `belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true`)

Comment: You may even want to create your own class, rather than a module.

Comment: Can I create an Address model without making a separate table? Making a table seems like overkill, and will introduce an unnecessary performance problem. This solution would basically mirror the java-based approach

Comment: What about a Plain Old Ruby Object, rather than a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build custom validators for the various types of validations you need, then invoke them in your model classes.

For example:

```
class PostalCodeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    unless value =~ /^\d{5}$/
      record.errors[attr_name] << "must be a 5-digit postal code"
    end
  end
```

Now use that validation in each model class and for each attribute that is a postal code. For instance, if you Customer has an attribute postal_code:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :postal_code, :postal_code => true
end
```

There's more detail and lots of fancy options, so I suggest a Google search on rails custom validators.

Comment: is it worth refactoring the actual fields too into a module or something like that? For example... address, postal code and province_id are basically always grouped together.

Comment: Are you going to add some serious functionality to that module, or just use it as a kind of struct? I'd do it if I had more than two classes that use those fields grouped together and if there were multiple methods associated with that group. The criterion for decision imo is whether you're actually simplifying things or just adding complexity.

Comment: Okay, I'll do the simple thing until that becomes not so wise anymore ;) Thanks